# Including a .propdesc file as a resource and registering it from DllRegisterServer

Tags: visual-studio, winapi, dll, properties, resources

I was wondering if it's possible to include a .propdesc file as a DLL resource and then to register it using `PSRegisterPropertySchema` from `DllRegisterServer`. I've been trying to figure out how to add it as a resource in Visual Studio, but I'm very lost on how to add that type of file.  Thank you for any guidance.

Comment: A property schema must be a file because Windows loads it and keeps it in memory as a cache (HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\PropertySystem\PropertySchema). You can add it as a resource to your DLL, but you'll have to extract it somewhere before registration. Also note you must run with elevated privileges to be able to succesfully register a schema.

Comment: Hm, then maybe it's easier just to ship it as a separate file.  Is that what you would do?

Comment: The resource is not a bad idea if you don't have a full setup process (but you'll have to extract it in a stable place). FWIW Office 365 uses a file: C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\Custom.propdesc maybe it's in their setup. If you use Program Files, it's probably easier with a file.

Comment: @loop123123 What kind of application do you develop? And do you have any concern of using general resource file: .rc?